# How to store a json data to a particular column in sqlite

Tags: javascript, json, sqlite

I am creating an application in which I would like to store the entire JSON data in a single column of a table is it possible in SQLite to store the entire JSON data into a particular column:

Example:
   {name:xxx xxx', age:25}  into the column details

[image: Table structure]

can anyone tell me how to store the JSON data in the above-mentioned structure in javascript.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Have you tried?

Comment: @Tigger I have tried this with using JSON.stingify.Is there anyway without using JSON.stringify

Answer (score 0):

You need a string representation to store it:

```
JSON.stringify(object)
```

Additionally it can filtered by required fields:

```
JSON.stringify(object, ['name', 'age'])
```

Comment: is there anyway without doing JSON.stringify